# How do you call 2 friends who are together without mixing it up with "a couple of friends"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am having a problem trying to translate something here.

I would like to explain that two of my friends (who are together, as a couple) are coming around, but I cannot find the right sentence for it.

If I say "a couple of friends" it really means that I am talking about two random friends. If I say "my two friends xx and xx, who are together" or similar, it just sounds really long and not natural.

What is the best way to put it ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you think "A couple of friends" implies random friends?  That isn't how it is usually interpreted.

Comment: It's enough for you to say **a couple**. So it would be like **a couple is coming around** and that's perfectly understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is right! Here, in *such sentences*, the word `couple` serves as a **determiner** [which means *'a small number of' or 'a few'*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/couple_1?q=couple). Probably that's why you call them 'random' friends.

When you specifically talk about two friends with **their names** *(as you wrote 'friend 'x' and friend 'xx' who are together)*, using the word 'couple' would cause some ambiguity.

Waht's the best way to put it then?

Well, call by their names. *"My friends Tom and Harry are coming out of the hall.*

---

In case you are talking about your friends Tom and Anna *(in a romantic relationship)*, it adds complexity! Here, 'couple' **does not mean** 'a few'. Here, [it is **for two persons**.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/couple)

The closest sentence for that is probably...

> *A couple who are my friends are coming out of the hall* **OR** 
> *A couple I'm friends with is coming...*

*Note* that it is **entirely** different from *'a couple of my friends'*. And, I think this is your confusion *(correct me if I'm wrong)*.

Comment: Very useful ! This is exactly where my confusion was, as I tried to talk about two persons in a romantic relationship coming to visit me. I find the last sentence "A couple I'm friends with" to be the most adequate. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

A lot depends on the emphasis you want

"My friend and his wife" or "my friend and her husband" may be possibilities though they imply that one of the couple is a closer friend of yours than the other.